# PHP mail() not sending a mail

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to learn a bit of basics of PHP, but as always I start from living examples like mailing. I'm not sure my tutorial was prepared good or I just made a couple of silly mistakes. There may be a problem with " ' because I haven't figured out which one should be where :) So, my mail is not sending an email, and definitely it's not going to spam so I believe I screw up ' and " part. Thanks for help!

```
$name = $_POST['nick'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$visitor_tel = $_POST['tel'];
$message = $_POST['msg'];

$email_from = 'mail@mail.pl';
$email_subject = "Nowe zlecenie: ";
$email_body = "Nowe zlecenie od $name.\n".
"Email kontaktowy: $visitor_email".
"Telefon kontaktowy: $visitor_tel".
"Zlecenie: $message".
$to = 'mail@mail.pl';
$headers = "Od: $email_from \r\n";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
```

Comment: Where are you running this code?

Comment: Hi, I'm using this in html, I'm not entirely sure that's what you mean :(

    <form id="contact-form" action="skrypt.php" method="post">

Comment: That is not what I asked. Are you running this on a server somewhere? Or on your personal computer?

Comment: I was running it on webmatrix (but only on localhost so it couldn't send out anything), but now on www server online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For debugging do like below:
if(mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers))
echo "mail sent";
else
echo "not send";

Comment: I got not send so @Qirel linked and I'm stuck at it: This is important to note because:

If you receive a FALSE return value you know the error lies with your server accepting your mail. This probably isn't a coding issue but a server configuration issue. You need to speak to your system administrator to find out why this is happening.

So I should already contact administrator or is there any chance to get it working by myself?

Comment: Yes in this case you should contact administrator.

Comment: I contacted them! They have told me that mail() is just old and I should use  PEAR::Net_SMTP, PEAR::Mail or phpMailer, @vishnu do you know maybe which one would be the best for this and is not that advanced?

Comment: You can use phpmailer library to send mails which is easy to use.